# Error while performing collect action on Spark RDD

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, collect

- JDK 1.8.0_141
- Spark 2.2 (installed with brew)

I am new to Spark, and just installed it using brew. In an **iPython notebook**, I created an RDD that's just a list of strings. I run some transformations on it, one being a mapping function that makes all items in the list a tuple, and the other being a reduceByKey function.

```
wordsList = ['cat', 'elephant', 'rat', 'rat', 'cat']
wordsRDD = sc.parallelize(wordsList, 4)
wordCountsCollected = (wordsRDD
                       .map(lambda w: (w, 1))
                       .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
                       .collect())
print(wordCountsCollected)
```

Everything works until I run collect on it. I get this Traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-88b98f07e38a> in <module>()
      4 wordCountsCollected = (wordsRDD
      5                        .map(lambda w: (w, 1))
----> 6                        .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
      7                        .collect())
      8 print(wordCountsCollected)

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 36.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 97, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.VerifyError: Bad instruction
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/spark/storage/ShuffleIndexBlockId.shuffleId()I @4: <illegal>
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0029 ec                           

    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getIndexFile(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommit(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:164)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad instruction
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/spark/storage/ShuffleIndexBlockId.shuffleId()I @4: <illegal>
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0029 ec                           

    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getIndexFile(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommit(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:164)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

iPython Notebook Imports

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)

import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
```

Simple command in spark-shell

```
Input >>> scala> spark.range(10).show
Output >>> 
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+
```

Comment: I suppose that install is broken. I'd propose to remove it and download it from spark.apache.org. Also check what JDK do you use.

Comment: Just try their version too (I've meant a possible binary error in an installation package). It won't take much time.

Comment: Since I've never done this before (I usually install everything magically with pip, and brew) I'm assuming I just unzip the file, and bring the downloaded directory to my python libraries directory ?

Comment: I am a java fellow, unfortunately I am not familiar how python loads it.

Comment: Can you use `spark-shell` instead and see if the following works: `spark.range(10).show`?

Comment: How did you install Spark? What was the brew command exactly? How did you start `pyspark`?

Comment: I have never seen this exception before @JacekLaskowski

Comment: Me either. That's why it's so interesting :)

Comment: I'd definitely check version for python and java. Maybe adding some info about the brew installation. Maybe something is broken at that level

Comment: @JacekLaskowski running that command in the shell works. I put the output in the question above. These were the commands I used 1. brew update 2. brew install scala 3. brew cask install java 4. brew install apache-spark 5. pyspark

Comment: Can you put the output of `pyspark` with the code exactly as you type it? I've tested that and it worked fine.

Comment: It actually works when I use pyspark. I'm sorry I didn't mention this, but I'm actually running this code in an iPython notebook.

Comment: I've edited the question to show my iPython notebook imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue to my problem. I was running a tutorial on iPython notebook, and it must be running on python2.7, a previous version of python that I had mainly running on my computer. I should've been tipped off by all the print statements that used the old syntax "print x" instead of print(x). Anyway an important library for using Apache Spark on iPython notebooks, **findspark**, was installed on python3.5, but not on python2.7, and after installing it on the older python version everything was copacetic. Moral of the story, Always Check Your Python Version :)! Thanks for your help everyone.